# Table of hex colors for NCAA teams?

Tags: color, color-reproduction

Greetings designers.

I've done enough googling to know that there are other people looking for this color table, but I can't find it for the life of me.  I'm close to trying to write a script to scrape this off wikipedia but thought I'd ask here first.

Has anyone found a table of NCAA Division 1 school colors?

Ideal format has columns for primary and secondary colors with hex codes. I apologize if this isn't an appropriate forum for this question, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried sites like colourlovers?

Comment: That's [a *lot* of colleges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NCAA_Division_I_institutions), enough that I suspect you're going to have trouble finding an already-made list.

Comment: Good point. The Wikipedia approach is probably best (start with Dori's link). Any official list would likely be in pantone colors not web colors, I imagine.

Comment: First question on here I'm stumped by. What is an NCAA team?

Comment: @e100 it's the college circuit in the US, eg Duke, WVU, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for letting this question get stale.  I'm primarily a Stack Overflow user, and was advised to post this question here.

I ended up writing a ruby script to search Wikipedia by school and team name, look for the school colors span tags and pull the background color values.  Results were surprisingly good.  I got about 80% of the division 1 teams primary and secondary colors on the first pass through and then did some spot checking and clean up.  I'll get around to posting this somewhere, if anyone else stumbles on this and is in need you can message me for the data.

Here's the google doc with the rough pull.  If you use this and do any cleanup, I'd appreciated you passing on the fixes :)

[Google spreadsheet: US Athletic Team Colors 0.1](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Agb4DJOM-AsTdFNBMjl1ODRaQkNMMmp1Z3dEUnFmdWc&hl=en)

Answer (score 9):

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/48147931/List-of-NCAA-Team-School-colors

How much do you love me?

Comment: This would have been very helpful and the price was right.  I needed secondary colors so I ended up doing the wiki scrape.  I don't have the rep to upvote this answer yet :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's the ruby script for the wikipedia tag scrape.

1. Select a batch of records from the DB
2. Fetch the wikipedia page
3. Perform an XPath search for the tags that might contain the color
4. Do a regex match for possible color attributes
5. Repeat until 2 matches are found
6. Write the 2 matches to the fields in the  DB record

Happy parsing.

```
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'sequel'
    @last = '"Tennessee-Martin"'

    DATABASE_FILE = '../development.sqlite3'

    DB = Sequel.sqlite('[your db path]/db/development.sqlite3') 
    @teamtags = DB.fetch('select teams.id as i, teams.name as t, tags.tag_value as n from teams, tags where tags.team_id = teams.id and tags.tag_name = "TeamName" and teams.name > ' + @last) 

    def hexColor(s)
        if (s =~ /(background|background-color):[ ]{0,1}#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}/)
            @match = %Q!#{$&}!
            @match =~ /#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}/
            @color = %Q!#{$&}!
            @colors[@matches] = @color
            return true
        end
    end

    @teamtags.each do |team|
        @searchterm = team[:t] + " "+ team[:n]

        @searchterm = @searchterm.gsub(/ /,"+")
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search="+@searchterm))

        @matches = 0
        @colors =["",""]
        # Print out each link using a CSS selector
        doc.xpath('//td//span').each do |span|
            #puts span
            if @matches < 2 
                #puts @matches
                if hexColor(span.to_s)
                    @matches = @matches + 1
                end
            end
        end
        puts team[:i].to_s + " => " + @colors[0] + " | " + @colors[1]
        DB[:teams].where(:id => team[:i]).update :primary_color => @colors[0], :secondary_color=>@colors[1]
        sleep 2 + rand(4)
    end
```

Comment: RSG - I was wondering If I could ask you about the ruby script as I would love something similar for a project I am working on dealing with college teams, The information collection is immense and I was hoping I could automate some of that as you stated you did with the team colors.

Comment: Posted.  Let me know if that doesn't work for you.